# Scroll ScrollView to focus on a specific child

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` with various elements, I have seen many ways to scroll programmatically at specific direction (`FOCUS_UP`, `FOCUS_DOWN` etc)

---

### |  CHILD-08  |

---

### |  CHILD-09  |

---

### |  CHILD-10  |<-----

---

### |  CHILD-11  |

---

### |  CHILD-12  |

---

### |  CHILD-13  |

Assuming that I want to scroll the `ScrollView` to focus on a specific child, how could I do?

Answer (score 0):

try creating **edittext** in a custom listview within your scrollview...
then use **setFocusableInTouchMode**